# Python format a string with a double inside quote with a dict

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

Why formatting with a dict when there is a double quote in the string fails?

```
'%(x)"%(y)' % {'x': 1, 'y':2}

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character '"' (0x22) at index 4
```

It works with :

```
'%s"%s' % (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you use `%s`, you should use `%(x)s`.  Just as `%"` is wrong, `%(x)"` is wrong.  You just need to add that little `s`:

```
'%(x)s"%(y)s' % {'x': 1, 'y':2}
```

That letter is required for the same reason it is required in normal formatting.  You could, as before, also use `d`, `03d`, `f`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting the conversion type code:

```
>>> '%(x)s"%(y)s' % {'x': 1, 'y':2}
'1"2'
```

Note the `s` strings. The syntax is `%(key)conversiontype`. Without a character signalling the conversion type, the parser picks the next character and that's `"` in your string.

From the [string formatting operations documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

> A conversion specifier contains two or more characters and has the following components, which must occur in this order:
>
> 1. The `'%'` character, which marks the start of the specifier.
> 2. Mapping key (optional), consisting of a parenthesised sequence of characters (for example, `(somename)`).
> 3. Conversion flags (optional), which affect the result of some conversion types.
> 4. Minimum field width (optional). If specified as an `'*'` (asterisk), the actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the object to convert comes after the minimum field width and optional precision.
> 5. Precision (optional), given as a `'.'` (dot) followed by the precision. If specified as `'*'` (an asterisk), the actual width is read from the next element of the tuple in values, and the value to convert comes after the precision.
> 6. Length modifier (optional).
> 7. Conversion type.

You gave items 1 and 2 (which is optional), but omitted item 7.